# React - HTML How to display my custom icon into <i> balise

Tags: html, reactjs

I wouldike to import my image into icon balise  :

```
import iconHome from "./images/icon_home.png";

    <NavItem eventKey="home">
                <NavIcon>
                  <i className="fa fa-fw fa-home" src={iconHome} style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                  Home
                </NavText>
              </NavItem>
```

But I show nothing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<i>` tag does not have `src` attribute. Use `img` tag instead

```
 <img src={iconHome} alt={"logo"}/>
```